# Bridge TCP connection to UDP (Bi-directional)

Tags: netcat

I have a device acting as a TCP server (192.168.240.1) on port 8080, and some software that can only connect via UDP to 0.0.0.0:XXXXX.

I setup forwarding of the TCP connection with netcat as follows:

```
nc 192.168.240.1 8080 | nc -u 0.0.0.0 63204
```

And this works to receive the data on the software which talks UDP, however, when I send something via UDP to port XXXXX (here 63204), it shows up in the terminal window and does not reach the device at 192.168.240.1.

I am not sure how to make this link bi-directional

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to do it, if anyone cares:

```
mkfifo backpipe
nc 192.168.240.1 8080 0<backpipe | nc -u 0.0.0.0 63204 1>backpipe
```